# Visual Studio: Is there a keyboard shortcut for search in the current line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

When editing code in VS, I typically use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to move to the line number that I want. It would be really nice if there's another keyboard shortcut that would allow me to move to the word that I want on that *same line* as well regardless of the cursor's position.

**Example:**

Say, I just moved to this line:

```
quint32       beamNum;              // Number of beams
```

and say I want to move to the word "Number"

typically I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> a few times (in this case exactly 4) to get to the word that I want. Imho, this is not fast enough.

I did try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> but it doesnt work for all cases because sometimes I want to search backward and if "Search Up" is not checked, it then becomes too slow.

Just wondering if anyone knows of such shortcut, if one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, Ctrl+G will take you to the first column of the line.  Then, you can press Ctrl+I (not an L) to begin an incremental search.  Now, start typing the word that you are looking for (case sensitive) and the IDE will move to the first match of what you're typing.  Hit Enter to end the incremental search.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks. Is there a shortcut for the "opposite" of Ctrl+I. e.g. instead of incremental search forward, it will incremental search backward.